# Do React.js and jQuery accomplish the same thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm new to Javascript and am trying to wrap my head around what you would use different frameworks for. Would a person use React and jQuery in the same project? Do they compliment or compete with each other? If they compete, why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are totally different things and ideas. Where React.JS is a framework that will be a replacement for the traditional view part in MVC.

jQuery is more a helper than a framework. It's a bundle of handy functions that will abstract a lot of javascript to make it easier to interact with for example the DOM. Or do things like ajax requests.

You could use jQuery and React.JS in the same project. Though it's not recommended to start changing the DOM with jQuery when you use React.JS because React.js uses an intelligent way to modify the DOM.

What would be a possible scenario is that you use React.JS for the view part and jQuery to do the request to fetch information from the server.